# Need suggestions to replace fuse in broken coffee warmer

Tags: identification, fuses

My coffee warmer suddenly stopped working after it did little sparky thing one day and I am trying to see if I can fix it.

I opened the cover and tested all the capacitors and diodes and everything looks fine. So my guess is it is a blown fuse (but not entirely sure). Here is the photo of the fuse:

[image]

Can someone confirm what kind of fuse I need to buy to replace this? When I searched all I was getting bulb type of fuse but this seems to be different.

Can I replace fuse (in the picture) with [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008QXVT4Y)?

Comment: It would be preferable if you could confirm that the problem is the fuse. A simple continuity test can answer this question.

Comment: A fuse just does not blow up without a cause. How did you teste all the capacitors and diodes? There are other components too than just capacitors and diodes, did you test them and how? Did you test the heater as well? It is impossible to say if replacing the fuse will fix it or will the fuse blow again. The picture is so blurry that you barely can see the fuse markings, and it is a different type of fuse so it can't by itself be used to replace the existing fuse.

Comment: "after it did little sparky thing" that's a pretty good indication that something else broke first, and caused the fuse to blow.

Comment: Try to get a picture looking straight down at the fuse, and making the writing on it as legible as possible.  You're looking for a fuse that's made to be soldered into a PC board; your picture is of a fuse that's made to be clipped into a holder.  They're not compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fuse is made by Dongguan Better Electronics, [datasheet](http://www.betterfuse.com/MyUploadFiles/Propath/932-SPEC_2020.01.25.pdf) can be found at the link.

You can find similar fuses made by other companies.

Chances are excellent something else is broken. If the MOV has died it may have taken the fuse out (the blue device with the shrink wrap). Alternatively it's possible the heater has failed in such a way that it shorted to itself or to ground, which would have killed the fuse. Or it could be something else not visible in your photo.

If it's the heater, repair is likely uneconomical. MOV would probably be worth replacing. You can poke around with an ohmmeter (power off, of course) to see where any short might be.